# How to run sails in watch mode(during development)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I started my new project in [sails](http://sailsjs.org/)(express on nodejs). I am currently starting my server using command

```
sails lift
```

But whenever I make changes, I need to restart my server. How do I start my server such a way any changes during development are automatically reflected on my localhost website?

Previously I created webserver using mean.io and starting server with command

```
grunt
```

used to start server in watch mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There [is a hook for that](https://github.com/sgress454/sails-hook-autoreload) for sails >= 0.11:

```
npm install sails-hook-autoreload
```

Here is how to configure it:

```
// [your-sails-app]/config/autoreload.js
module.exports.autoreload = {
  active: true,
  usePolling: false,
  dirs: [
    "api/models",
    "api/controllers",
    "api/services"
  ]
};
```

**Models, controllers or services will be reloaded without having to relift the app**

---

Alternatively, you could use [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to start your app.

```
// In a terminal, from the root directory of your project
forever -w -o log/out.log -e log/err.log app.js
```

The `-w` option restarts the app on file changes. You can use a `.foreverignore` file to exclude some paths:

```
// [your-sails-app]/.foreverignore
**/.tmp/**
**/views/**
**/assets/**
**/log/**
```

With this solution, **the app will be completely stopped and restarted but you can use it with any version of sails** and there is not this limitation from the `sails-hook-autoreload` documentation:

> As for now, it's not possible to add new directories to be reloaded.

Comment: If I use sails-hook-reload. Everytime I get a error(500 error) server stops compeltely!

Comment: I've just tried sails-hook-autoreload, but they didn't work for me. Changes are so simple, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've reported the issue here. https://github.com/sgress454/sails-hook-autoreload/issues/45